# How to implement Save Or Update Button. Client Side

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I was tasked to create a web page, that allows the users to log in and update their stock. I was asked to create a save and an update button.

I was asked to use the update button only if the client is happy that all details are correct and ready to submit.

The save button is for the clients to be able to save their selections. So for instance if the client has only completed part of the update, the user can re-visit the webpage to update at a later point in time, and would not be updating the database.

I was told that you can save the variables on the client's machine. I can't find any details online on where to start with this...

Basically I have a gridview that has 5 dropdownlists and I would like the dropdownlists to keep state even on their next visit so they can complete and update.

Can anybody point me in the correct direction? Many thanks.

Comment: Search how to save cookies on client machine browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), which stores data in the browser and persists between sessions.

However, be warned that this only happens for that specific browser. If the user uses your website from a different browser on the same computer, or logs in from a different computer, that data won't be available.

If you need the data to be available for the same user from one session to the next, it should be stored on the server.